# loglinear analysis, assumptions met?

Tags: assumptions, log-linear

We've data from a large ongoing project at a big science museum. We are showing people plates of food where we vary the plate shape (round or square; 0,1), food arrangement (polygonal or vertical arrangement; 0,1) and the number of items on the plate (3 scallops or 4). For each pair of plates+food, we ask the individual which they prefer. A person will only ever get trials where there are 3 vs 4 items on a plate. Below are our frequencies.

edit:

- I have added 'test' which details which item x plate x arrangement
  was tested with which other such grouping.
- where 'weight' is the number of times the people decided one grouping (item x plate x arrangement) was preferred over another in a given text.

> items,plate,arrangement,test,weight
>
> 3,1,1,1,249
>
> 3,1,0,1,177
>
> 3,0,1,2,282
>
> 3,0,0,2,184
>
> 4,1,1,3,243
>
> 4,1,0,3,297
>
> 4,0,1,4,185
>
> 4,0,0,4,281

I originally used loglinear analysis. I have a doubt though about this study. It feels as if some assumption has not been met. My question is: do you think this data is valid for such an analysis? Our criteria of only showing participants plates where there were 3 vs 4 items of food is bothersome.

For the curious, here is the loglinear model output ([pdf](http://www.opensourcesci.com/temp/spss.pdf)).

Comment: a couple questions - are all the predictors (plate, arrangement, number of items) included as independent categorical variables? are interactions included? the outcome variable is prefer/don't prefer?

Comment: Dear Nick. Yes, all predictors are included. Log-linear stepwise analysis is including all possible interactions. Thanks.

Comment: Is your research question focused on the contribution of each variable (+ interactions)? I wouldn't collapse plate preferences into the weight variable for this design if that's the case. If this seems like an appropriate position, I'd be happy to amend my answer and write a quick R script to implement my suggestion so you can see concretely what I mean

Comment: Dear Ghonke, yes, we are keen on testing whether 3 is preferred over 4 scallops, and whether plate shape influences this. What about the absence of round plate vs square plate tests? Must admit this is quite a brain buster!

Answer (score 1):

edit: this answer needs to be updated given new information provided in the question

I say you're meeting the assumptions of the test. Your intuition about 3 vs 4 scallops as a predictor variable might come from this:

As I've read it, you've got a series of categorical variables predicting a binomial preference  dependent variable (preferring a plate or not).

This design doesn't violate assumptions (as long as you're treating number scallops as categorical) but it might end up being under-powered (depending on n) as compared to a design that had integer predictors (like if you had 1-2-3-4-5 as number-of-scallops sub-conditions). I think that's what might be bothering you, but not much to do about it now, as these are the sub-conditions chosen for the experiment.

You might argue that the number-of-scallops predictor could be included as a numeric variable but consider that baked into that is the assumption that 0, 10, 50 100 scallops are possible values for the number-of-scallops predictor variable.

So if my read is correct, it's a logistic regression predicting plate preference with 3 categorical variables and I'd say you're using the technique appropriately.

Comment: Please follow orthodox spelling and punctuation. Your writing is unnecessarily difficult to read.

Comment: I understand weight to mean frequency of choices.

Comment: not sure i follow, @NickCox, but i gave it a shot